# If the client keeps on changing the requirements every now and then, then what testing method should be followed?

Tags: testing, integration-testing, manual-testing

I always perform regression testing as soon as the changes come up. The case is the client comes up with changes or additional requirement every now and then and that makes the case more messy. I test something and then the whole things get changed. Again I have to test the changed module and perform integration testing with other modules that is linked with it.

How to deal with such cases?

Comment: Sounds like most software development processes. As long as the client is explained that changing requirements means either changing scope elsewhere; or a larger cost and delayed deadlines - then I'd just continue to treat it as normal development and do what you do. You'll most likely never find "one way to suit all" (and if you do, you'll be rich selling books)

Comment: Sounds good enough. Major concern is few modules are repeatedly tested due to some change in another module linked with. Anyway, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) 1st ask complete Clint requirement and note every small point in doc.

2) Understand that total functionality.

3) Use your default testing method.

4) Your not mention which type your testing.( app or portal )

5) As well as possible which is comfortable and feel easy you continue that testing.

6) You want automation testing.please use this (App-appium or Web-selenium)

I hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: This is not the question. I have all the docs in hand. Still after every week release, client wants something or another to get changed or to get removed. This increases testing of many modules very frequently. I think there is no specific solution to this unless the client understands. Still thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you the following things

->Initially gather all the requirements and check with the client if you have any queries through email.

->Document every thing in MOM whenever you have client call and share with everyone who has attended the call(dev team,client,business,QA)

->Prepare a Test Plan strategy document, test cases and share it to client and request him for his sign off.

->Once, you are all set start with smoke testing then check the major functionalities in that release and then could proceed further.

->You could automate the regression test cases as you are going to execute them for every release(I would suggest to use Selenium if its a desktop application then UFT).

Kindly, let me know if you have any queries.